# Properly Encoding Static Image Data for NextJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, image-processing, next.js

I'm trying a purely static approach on a new project Next v12 project, building up 5-6 data files to feed into `getStaticProps`. Here's one of the shapes of the data file (but they're all similar):

```js
import SqAshland1 from '../../public/best-places-imagery/square-ashland.jpg'

const bestPlacesList = [
   {
    "cityName": "Ashland",
    "state": "WI",
    "country": "US",
    "imageSquare": SqAshland1,
    "slug": "ashland-wi"
   }, 
   ...
]

const encodeBestPlacesList = JSON.stringify(bestPlacesList)
export default bestPlacesList
```

This is what it looks like when I inject this file in my `/pages/best-places/[slug].js`:

```js
export async function getStaticProps({ params, preview = false, previewData }) {
  
  const parsedBestPlacesList = JSON.parse(bestPlacesList)
  const cityData = parsedBestPlacesList.find( city => city.slug === params.slug )

  return {
    props: {
      preview,
      cityData: cityData,
    },
    revalidate: 60,
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const cities = JSON.parse(bestPlacesList);

  return {
    paths: cities?.map( (city) => ({
      params: { slug: city.slug }
    })),
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```

It's working well, but the images keep breaking when I deploy. This makes me think I need to do base64 encoding for the images but where do I do this so I don't break Next's image fetching? Curious if anyone has tried this approach and knows how to balance Next and Node just right.

Comment: Could you accept my answer if this is what you are looking for or comment if it doesn't.

Comment: Do you need to statically import the local images that way? Could you not simply save the path to the image in the `public` folder instead, i.e. `"imageSquare":  "/best-places-imagery/square-ashland.jpg"`? Then use that as the `next/image`'s source.

Comment: @juliomalves - doesn't next automatically bundle everything in the `/public` folder with webpack and create unique URLs?

Comment: `next/image` will create unique URLs for the images when it generates the optimised images. Those optimised images are then served from the Next.js server (when using the default loader). However, my point was that you could reference local images from their paths inside the `public` folder as strings, rather than using `import img from <path>`, as it would probably simplify your logic.

Comment: That's a nice insight. I thought you had to `import` to get the images to work with Next. Maybe `next/image` is the right answer and I'm just not using it right.

Answer (score 2):

1. Personally, I think base64 would be right to use here. It would be best to use bease64 encoding together with the data URI scheme (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

You could use the following helper function to get an image base 64 encode with the URI scheme

```
// Helper function
function base64EncodeJpg(file) {
    return "data:image/jpg;base64," + fs.readFileSync(file, 'base64');
}
```

2. Use the helper function when you create the `bestPlacesList`

```
const bestPlacesList = [
   {
    "cityName": "Ashland",
    "state": "WI",
    "country": "US",
    "imageSquare": base64EncodeJpg('../../public/best-places-imagery/square-ashland.jpg'),
    "slug": "ashland-wi"
   }, 
   ...
]
```

3. to make sure the paths will work both in production and development you could make use of a .env file where you define a base path for the image assets and use this instead of the relative paths.
   https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables

Comment: Have you tried this method? I will give it a shot. The thing is that next bundles imagery and the paths are unique every time. You have to do the image as an import AFAIK.

Comment: Erwin I gave you the bounty as a participation award so thanks for answering! I'm not sure this is actually the right answer though. Julio's suggestion is similar to yours above, perhaps I'm just overthinking this and you can do straight file references to the `/public` folder. I will experiment and report back.